# Get ip adress without using a link ... in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So ... i want to get the **EXTERNAL IP** in vb.net ... ( not internal 192.168.0.100 ) without using any link like http://www.whatismyip.com ... so i make a lot of searches on google and i got a code :

```
Public Function IpAddress()
    Dim strIpAddress As String
    strIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
    If strIpAddress = "" Then
        strIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    End If
    IpAddress = strIpAddress
End Function
```

or

```
dim blabla as string = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

i import sistem.web and sistem.net 
**i install the web developer kit and asp.net too **but nothing*** ...*
*Request is not declarated*

then i put in the front of request **HttpContext.Current**...
*HttpContext.Current.request....*

**and i got this error:**
*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Comment: If it's not an ASP.NET application you won't get a Request.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer doesn't even know its external IP address. You have to ask an external computer because you can't see the external IP from the inside.

Comment: aham ... but i can do somehow to host temporary a page with the code $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] or something like and then access the page and got the ip :D ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Constantin Berhard say, you should ask outside.

For example, you can use a webservice. You could develop it or just use your known whttismyip.

Here you have all the info about the API you could use.

http://www.whatismyip.com/api-documentation/

Comment: and again my program will depending on a link if the link changes/die my program will not work anymore ...

Comment: Ok, so you need to ask somewhere outside but being isolated from the outside... Nice Paradox! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the server has an external domain name, you can do a DNS lookup on that domain name. You'll be depending on an external service, but not a particular service.

```
dim host as IPHostEntry = GetHostEntry("example.com")
```